# ¿Como cambiar etiquetas en un menú android?

Tags: android

cree un activity con tabs y por default me sale con el menú lateral pero no se como configurar para poder cambiar el nombre que sale por default y ponerle mas etiquetas en el menú

este es archivo xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

el archivo java

```
package com.josemoya.happytoby;

import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
 import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;

 import android.widget.TextView;

  public class HappyToby extends AppCompatActivity {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.happytoby);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("HappyToby");

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);



}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main2, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}




/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Tab1agenda tab1 = new Tab1agenda();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                Tab2salud tab2 = new Tab2salud();
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                Tab3alimen tab3 = new Tab3alimen();
                return tab3;
            case 3:
                Tab4mapa tab4 = new Tab4mapa();
                return tab4;
            default:
                return null;
        }

    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Tab1agenda tab1 = new Tab1agenda();
                return "Agenda";
            case 1:
                Tab2salud tab2 = new Tab2salud();
                return "Salud";
            case 2:
                Tab3alimen tab3 = new Tab3alimen();
                return "Alimentación";


        }
        return null;

    }

}

  }
```

El settings quiero cambiar pero no se donde

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido José. ¿Te refieres a `HappyToby`? El título se establece aquí en tu código: `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("HappyToby");`. Por favor, indica cómo se llama el archivo `xml` que estás mostrando... Me parece que lo de `Settings` lo estás presentando aquí: `getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main2, menu);`, es posible que esté en un XML llamado `menu_main2.xml` en la carpeta de menues.

Answer (score 0):

vas a

> res - menu

y donde tienes los drawables de menu tienes los `<items>` , ahi en items tienes el `action_settings`, puedes ponerle un label o nombre nuevo

Answer (score -2):

Tienes que revisar dentro del archivo que crea el menú, que en este caso es `menu_main2.xml` :

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main2, menu);
```

y se debe encontrar en esta ubicación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este archivo debe tener un  en el cual se define el nombre y puedes cambiarlo mediante la propiedad:

```
android:title
```

Puedes cambiar directamente el nombre :

```
android:title="Configuración"
```

o también puedes almacenar el texto en strings.xml y obtenerlo mediante la referencia a este archivo.

```
android:title="@string/titulo_settings"
```